# Maximum files size for Pyspark RDD

Tags: python, linux, apache-spark, pyspark

I’m practicing Pyspark (standalone) in the Pyspark shell at work and it’s pretty new to me. Is there a rule of thumb regarding max file size and the RAM (or any other spec) on my machine? What about when using a cluster?

The file I’m practicing with is about 1200 lines. But I’m curious to know how large of a file size can be read into an RDD in regards to machine specifications or cluster specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard limit on the Data size you can process, however when your RDD (Resilient Distributed Dataset) size exceeds the size of your RAM then the data will be moved to Disk. Even after the data is moved to the Disk spark will be equally capable of processing it. For example if your data is 12GB and available memory is 8GB spark will distribute the leftover data to disk and takes care of all transformations / actions seamlessly. Having said that you can process the data appropriately equal to size of disk.

There are of-course size limitation on size of single RDD which is 2GB. In other words the maximum size of a block will not exceed 2GB.